# How to convert curl data to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

i am sending my request to corss domain to get the xml data ,here i am making curl request to get the data from diferent domain . i am getting the data but i want to use that data using javascript .Below is my curl code it's in seprate file. call -> **air.php**

```
<?php
$url = "http://xmlfltdata.ifids.com/ifids/EDIAirportXMLData.asp?apt=YKF&pwd=mk37";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$getData = curl_exec($curl);
```

so if i do var_dump($getData) i am getting request back.
Now i have anothr file call :**airport.php**

```
<h1>Flight Details</h1>
<span style="font-size: 18px;color: #61966C">
<p id='showFlight'></p>
</span>
<table id="flightInfo"></table>
<script>

    var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");


    xmlhttp.open("get","air.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;   

    var FlightData = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Header");

    table="<tr><th>FlightNumber</th><th>Arrival || Departure</th></tr>";

    for (i = 0; i < FlightData.length; i++)
    {  //do somethign here
     }
```

Now i am not able to make the Ajax request to get the data from my curl file .How can i make request to get that data in javascript.
Please Help

Comment: if the api you are calling only return xml you need to parse it into JS, no way to just get it in a different format than they send back, this has nothing to do with curl data, the api `xmlfltdata` return only that type apparantly

Comment: One step at a time. First make sure you can get a basic Ajax request working. Then try one with curl.

Comment: Hi i am not getting Ajax request from the curl.